# Error al instalar JWT en laravel 8

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-8

estoy iniciando un proyecto con la backend en laravel 8 pero se me hace imposible instalar JWT

```html
Using version ^0.5.12 for tymon/jwt-auth
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update tymon/jwt-auth
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires tymon/jwt-auth ^0.5.12 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.12].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.12 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo que he podido buscar es algún tipo de incompatibilidad de JWT con php 8 o laravel 8 no estoy seguro, alguien podria confirmarme o que deberia de hacer... instalar una versión distinta de laravel o de PHP o si fuese posible alguna versión funcional para laravel 8

Comment: parace que jwt depende de otro paquete que no puede ser actualizado por la version, intenta subir o bajar la version del otro paquete en el composer.json o instalar una version menor de jwt

Comment: uh... la versión `0.5.x` de jwt-auth es del 2017. Te aseguro que no tienes Laravel 8. Puedes correr `php artisan --version`  y  `composer why illuminate/support`?

Comment: pues realmente si tengo laravel 8 y php 8 porque yo mismo actualiza php y composer para instalar la ultima version http://prntscr.com/102nanj